# Does linker recognise namespace alias?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, linker

I'm compiling a program on Windows using vs2008, I get a linker error LNK2019, my object file has a unresolved symbol

```
func(boost::shared_ptr<Type> x)
```

The library A I'm linking is supposed to define this symbol, but *dumpbin* shows the symbol defined is

```
func(boost_1_53_0::shared_ptr<Type> x)
```

I think the boost library is using bcp to make boost a alias of boost_1_53_0, but does the linker know about namespace alias?

If not, where does this build go wrong?

Comment: You don't have a macro that defines `boost`  to be `boost_1_53_0`?

Comment: In my app's code? No, why do I need that? It will hardcore boost dependency to 1.53.

Comment: I'm asking because that could be a reason for the `boost_1_53_0` namespace name. So no you should not add such a macro.

Comment: No I don't think such macro is manually defined, it's added(I think) by boost bcp when this boost version is built

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is: no, the linker doesn't care about namespace alias, all symbols should be unified, the problem here is library A was not build correctly with boost 1.53.

Answer (score 0):

no, this is not the problem. Could we see your code? probably you need to include the header. It look like forwarding, but shared_ptr is a template class. so forwarding is not a good idea

Comment: Are you saying the linker should be able to resolve the symbol? I'm not allowed to paste code here, what do you mean by forwarding?

Comment: forwarding is when you don't include the header in the .hpp file and use class name; to indicate the linker that the class exist in other file. It look so because you have boost::shated_ptr instead boost::shared_ptr <Name>

Comment: forwarding is used to avoid circular dependence in header files

Comment: in other words change boost::shared_ptr to boost::shared_ptr <Name> and include the header

Comment: Sorry shared_ptr but not shared_ptr<T> was my fault, the actually error does have it, and shared_ptr.hpp is included, why would forwarding cause linking error?

Comment: ok. if the header of type is included, than it is not forwardin problem.  Ok your question: shared ptr is a template so you cant firward. you can forward Type but then the header muss be in the .cpp file. the other question. the alias are solve when the code is compiled, so alias should disaper in the object files. in other words the aluas us not the problem.

Comment: you can try use std::shared_ptr from the standart library but i think the problem will be the same